# Arch Linux | No updates in repository

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

After 5 days with zero updates, doing daily checks with `pacman -Syyu` got a big 1GB amount of updates, why this happens?

I'm new in Arch Linux, I wish this is only a coincidence and not something bad.

Comment: Alright, thanks Peregrino69.

Comment: NP friend :-) I'm struggling to understand why this is an issue to you. Personally I don't see anything that would be cause for concern. I'm pretty sure it is just a coincidence. On another note - Arch is known to have one of the best, most active communities around. If you haven't yet registered in [Arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/), you really are missing out :-) SuperUser as a community is about SW and HW in general, Unix&Linux are more focused - but for Arch-specific questions like this nothing beats its own community :-)

Comment: Yep, I remember, you said that before in another question made by me hahaha, sorry for that, I'll remember this time.

Comment: I'll go to Arch Forums right now! Thanks for the help Peregrino69, for real!

Comment: LOL I did? :-D Well, it's a good enough resource to warrant reminding :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check the Arch Linux website for any news posts from the last few days that might be relevant.
2. If there aren't any news posts, check the website's "Packages" section and look up the information for some recently-updated packages, comparing the version in the website with what's shown by `pacman -Si`.
3. If the shown versions differ, and if they continue to be different after a `-Syy[u]` database refresh, it means your selected *package mirror* has an outdated copy of the database – it has stopped synchronizing from its parent server for whatever reason. (Maybe it ran out of space or something.)
4. Find out *which* package mirror you're using – it's in pacman's configuration files, most often in the separate `mirrorlist` file. For each repository, the first server in the list is the one that'll be used every time.
5. Check the "Mirror Status" section of the website to find out if the mirror is prone to such problems (and whether it's even still in the list at all), and look through the list for nearby alternatives.

   Nearly all Arch mirror servers are independently run by various sponsors and volunteers without any guarantee on service quality; only 2-3 are actually run by Arch staff.
6. Edit your pacman configuration to use the new mirror instead of the broken one (and add a couple of fallback URLs), or optionally use the website's "Mirrorlist generator" or other similar tools.
7. <del>Carefully collect the shards of the broken mirror so as to not cut your feet.</del>

Comment: I have 3 mirrrors from Spain, It could be the time Spain was outdated in comparison to the updates in other countries (I think)

Comment: Thanks for the help user1686, this is very useful to me and for the community!